# How do I align arithmetic problems?

Tags: math-mode, formatting

If I wanted to align 2-digit multiplication with the line underneath, how would I do it?
For example, if I wanted to multiply 32 × 45 and I wanted to multiply them in a vertical column, what command would I use? I am a huge beginner.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I could guess that you want to use `align` to align something. But really, we need something to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{r}
12\\
\times\ 3\\
\hline
36
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```